# Determine type signature in elm script

Tags: types, functional-programming, elm

As I am learning church encoding and try to reduce complexity, so I use `elm` to implement the code. But I came over a point that I could not figure out the type signature.

```
type alias Peano = (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int

fwd : Int -> Int
fwd x = x + 1

c3 : Peano
c3 f = 
    f >> f >> f

cExp: ???
cExp cm cn =
    cn cm
```

However, in `elm-repl`

```
> cExp cm cn = cn cm
<function> : a -> (a -> b) -> b
> cExp c3
<function> : (((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> b) -> b
> cExp c3 c3
<function> :  (a -> a) -> a -> a
> cExp c3 c3 fwd
<function> : number -> number
> cExp c3 c3 fwd 0
27 : number
```

So using equational reasoning in functional thinking, I substitute the types as:

```
a -> (a -> b) -> b
as
Peano -> (Peano -> (Int -> Int)) -> (Int -> Int)
                         ^            ^
                        fwd           0
```

Therefore,

```
cExp c3 c3 fwd 0 = 27
```

What could be the problem?

I was wondering is this a problem related to infinite type in `elm`,  but I do not have enough knowledge to comprehend what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining `Peano` in terms of `Int`, when really the arguments could be functions. You should make it more generic:

```elm
type alias Peano a = (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Now you'll have to update your Church numerals:

```elm
c3 : Peano a
c3 f = 
    f >> f >> f
```

*(side note: Elm's `>>` operator is function composition but in reverse direction. It may be more idiomatic to use the regular function composition operator, `<<`, which is equivalent to Haskell's `.` operator)*

And your exponent function can be annotated like this:

```elm
cExp : a -> (a -> b) -> b
cExp cm cn =
    cn cm
```